# Attempting to replicate each row in a pandas dataframe a certain number of times

Tags: python

Sample Data:

```
X  | a | c
41 | 5 | 2
54 | 3 | 1
```

Transformation:

```
X  | a | c
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
41 | 5 | 2
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
54 | 3 | 1
```

I've done this in R using the following command:

```
data_final[rep(1:nrow(data_final),each=nrow(expand.grid(0:6)),]
```

but I'm not quite sure how I'd do this in python.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas + numpy solution with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

If all columns have same dtypes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 7, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     X  a  c
0   41  5  2
1   41  5  2
2   41  5  2
3   41  5  2
4   41  5  2
5   41  5  2
6   41  5  2
7   54  3  1
8   54  3  1
9   54  3  1
10  54  3  1
11  54  3  1
12  54  3  1
13  54  3  1
```

If not:

```
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index, 7)].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     X  a  c  d
0   41  5  2  a
1   41  5  2  a
2   41  5  2  a
3   41  5  2  a
4   41  5  2  a
5   41  5  2  a
6   41  5  2  a
7   54  3  1  r
8   54  3  1  r
9   54  3  1  r
10  54  3  1  r
11  54  3  1  r
12  54  3  1  r
13  54  3  1  r
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
pd.concat([dat]*6, ignore_index = True).sort_values('X').reset_index(drop = True)
#     X  a  c
#0   41  5  2
#1   41  5  2
#2   41  5  2
#3   41  5  2
#4   41  5  2
#5   41  5  2
#6   54  3  1
#7   54  3  1
#8   54  3  1
#9   54  3  1
#10  54  3  1
#11  54  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `.repeat` on your index, passing the resulting array to `.reindex`, and then resetting your index with `drop=True`:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(6)).reset_index(drop=True)

#      X  a  c
# 0   41  5  2
# 1   41  5  2
# 2   41  5  2
# 3   41  5  2
# 4   41  5  2
# 5   41  5  2
# 6   54  3  1
# 7   54  3  1
# 8   54  3  1
# 9   54  3  1
# 10  54  3  1
# 11  54  3  1
```